# JavaScript code for HTML5 canvas element will not work - includes a loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, canvas

I'm currently making a website, and have recently discovered the wonders of HTML5 canvas.

I have made a triangle using HTML5 canvas and JavaScript (*simple, I know*).

I will be placing a triangle after each section of the webpage to indicate the user should continue to scroll down. I will be using multiple triangles on the webpage, each in a different colour (*yes, I spell it that way*).

So, I want to make a function that uses an array of the canvas elements on the page to change the colour of each of the triangles. For example the first will be blue, the second red, and the third yellow.

Here is the code so far.
**Problem**: it does not work! Where have I gone wrong? Do you have a better solution? I am new to Stack Overflow.

```
// declare all global variables

var allCanvasElements = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas');

var canvasArrayLength = allCanvasElements.length;

function canvasLoop() {

    // create canvas
    var c = allCanvasElements[i];
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    for (i = 0; i < canvasArrayLength; i++) {
        // canvas code
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(60,0);
        ctx.lineTo(30,30);

        // selects current canvas, gives colour
        if (c == allCanvasElements[i]) {
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        }

        // fills and strokes the canvas
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();        
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", canvasLoop(), false);
```

Comment: In the first line of the function, you say `var c = allCanvasElements[i];`. What do you expect `i` to contain at that point? Which element do you expect to select? Have you checked that `i` and `c` contain what you expect?

Comment: var c = allCanvasElements[i]; at the beginning of your function - i is still undefined.

Comment: Also, since you never declar `var i` anywhere, you're using the global `i`. It may (a) already have a too-high or -low value from some other code or (b) mess up other code if this function is called within a loop that also uses `i`.

Comment: _"Do you have a better solution?"_ yes use image sprite and css styled elements instead of drawing on a canvas. But along with all the other errors mentioned you are also not setting the event listener correctly, `("load", canvasLoop, false);`

Comment: Indeed. I know drawing in the canvas is fun, but that's very useless in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys @PatrickEvans I quite like canvas, I feel it will be a very versatile, and useful tool for me when I get to grips with it, and even in the future when 3d canvas is developed etc. To be clear: a) There's no need for empty parentheses after canvasLoop in the event listener? b) Image spite is superior to HTML5 Canvas? Or I should use it instead of canvas?

Comment: Both your post and your answer are useless, please delete them.

Comment: @GameAlchemist What's with the hate? I was just trying to get some help, and then solved my problem?

Comment: No hate, just describing. Your post falls into a close category, it'd be faster if you deleted it. ( Category : Off topic / This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting. )

Comment: @GameAlchemist Fine, okay. I answered too quickly so no one else can contribute? Again, I'm new here. Did you like the code though and understand what I was trying to do?

Comment: Your post falls into a close category, it'd be faster if you deleted it. ( Category : Off topic / This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting. )

Answer (score 0):

literally just read through the code again after posting, and found that I was using using 'i' to find the current element in the canvas array before I had even declared the loop that uses 'i'. Silly me! A quick change, now it works just fine. Now, on to the rest of the Canvas elements! Here is the corrected code if you're interested -

// declare all global variables

var allCanvasElements = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas');

var canvasArrayLength = allCanvasElements.length;

function canvasLoop() {

```
// create canvas
var c = allCanvasElements[i];
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

for (i = 0; i < canvasArrayLength; i++) {
    // canvas code
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(60,0);
    ctx.lineTo(30,30);

    // selects current canvas, gives colour
    if (c == allCanvasElements[i]) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    }

    // fills and strokes the canvas
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();        
}
```

}

window.addEventListener("load", canvasLoop(), false);